# Audio on my MacBook stops working while using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, macbook-pro, macosx

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina). I run Ubuntu on VirtualBox and every time that I run Ubuntu, the audio on my Mac stops working. It starts working after I close Ubuntu. I am not sure what I can do, it would be great if someone could help me.